# Serve static files in symfony and apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have a project in symfony and apache, also, I have a `web/images` folder where I store some images.

The problem is that when I type the following url: `mydomain:app_dev.php/images/myimage.png`
I get back this error:

```
No route found for GET /images/myimage.png
```

Any other url works fine.

Why is this happening? why cant this just be like a plain apache website where you type in the image url and get it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links that use static content should not use `app_dev.php` or `app.php`. This will allow it to be retrieved as if it was a 'plain apache website' or what ever web server you are using.

This should work the way you want it to.

`mydomain:images/myimage.png`

Comment: What would happen if my virtual host points directly to app_dev.php? What work around could I use?